# Python Loop is repeating more than 1 time

Tags: python

I need to loop an action that contains 2 lists, but when I try to loop it, it loops more than 1 time for each list inside. It's hard to explain.
Here is my code:

```
import os

#pregunta el Path
userPath=("/mnt/die/go")

#Hace la lista de objetos
lista = ("r.alas", "r.guantes","r.cabeza","r.res")      

# Corta la Lista para tener solo objeto
listaCorta = []

for each in lista:
    listaCorta.append  (str(each).split(".")[1])

for lis in lista:   
    for r in listaCorta:
        direccion='%s/%s_1.pc2' % (userPath, r)
        print lis,direccion
```

This is what I get:

```
# r.alas /mnt/die/go/alas_1.pc2
# r.alas /mnt/die/go/guantes_1.pc2
# r.alas /mnt/die/go/cabeza_1.pc2
# r.alas /mnt/die/go/res_1.pc2
# r.guantes /mnt/die/go/alas_1.pc2
# r.guantes /mnt/die/go/guantes_1.pc2
# r.guantes /mnt/die/go/cabeza_1.pc2
# r.guantes /mnt/die/go/res_1.pc2
# r.cabeza /mnt/die/go/alas_1.pc2
# r.cabeza /mnt/die/go/guantes_1.pc2
# r.cabeza /mnt/die/go/cabeza_1.pc2
# r.cabeza /mnt/die/go/res_1.pc2
# r.res /mnt/die/go/alas_1.pc2
# r.res /mnt/die/go/guantes_1.pc2
# r.res /mnt/die/go/cabeza_1.pc2
# r.res /mnt/die/go/res_1.pc2
# ('r.alas', '/mnt/die/go/res_1.pc2')
# ('r.guantes', '/mnt/die/go/res_1.pc2')
# ('r.cabeza', '/mnt/die/go/res_1.pc2')
# ('r.res', '/mnt/die/go/res_1.pc2')
```

I just need one of each, like this:

```
r.ala , /mnt/die/go/alas_1.pc2
r.guantes , /mnt/die/go/guantes_1.pc2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loops

```
for lis in lista:   
    for r in listaCorta:
        direccion='%s/%s_1.pc2' % (userPath, r)
        print lis,direccion
```

is what is causing the looping. 
So you need to do this:

```
for lis in lista:
    direccion='%s/%s_1.pc2' % (userPath, str(lis).split(".")[1])
```

This way you can get rid of 1 for loop altogether.

```
import os
userPath=("/mnt/die/go")

lista = ("r.alas", "r.guantes","r.cabeza","r.res")

for lis in lista:   
    direccion='%s/%s_1.pc2' % (userPath, str(lis).split(".")[1])
    print lis, direccion
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
for each in lista:   
    direccion='%s/%s_1.pc2' % (userPath, str(each).split(".")[1])
    print lis,direccion
```

instead of all your loops.

Answer (score 0):

Split the original string, create the 'direccion' variable and print them inside the first loop. A command block inside a for loop (that's inside another one) is executed m x n times (where m is the size of outter loop and n the size of inner loop).